# Get childnode's children until there aren't any

Tags: javascript, html, children, domparser

I'm using `DOMParser()` to parse a HTML string, and am trying to get all the child nodes with a for loop. However I do not know how to get the child nodes' nodes, and their children, etc...

```
var str = "<div><p>paragraph<span>span</span></p></div>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
var childnodes = doc.body.childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < childnodes.length; i++) {
    console.log(childnodes[i]);
    console.log(childnodes[i].childNodes);
    console.log(childnodes[i].childNodes[i].childNodes);
}
```

This works as I'd like, it gives the `div`, `p`, `text`, and `span`, but how would I make this work with a for loop that gets all the grandchildren? Without jQuery?

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shub01/0m61ctex/) with the above code.

Comment: You’ll probably want to use recursion for this.

Comment: Is there any reason `doc.body.querySelectorAll('*')` wouldn't work ?

Comment: @adeneo that won't give text nodes will it?

Comment: @adeneo then I can't use it! :(

Comment: @CBroe I think that will work, looking at juvian's answer! Thanks :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0m61ctex/1/

Comment: @adeneo hmmm - I don't understand how that works - if you could comment it and post it as an answer, I could look at it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Nah, seems uneccessary complicated, the answers below are fine.

Comment: @adeneo lol; fair enough! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use recursion for this:

```
function travelChildren(childnodes){

    for (var i = 0; i < childnodes.length; i++) { // for each node in childnodes
        console.log(childnodes[i]); // console log current node
        travelChildren(childnodes[i].childNodes) // and travel its children
    }

}

travelChildren(childnodes) // start recursion with the child nodes you want
```

Comment: Ahhh - I see how this works! Sorry; I'd never heard of recursion before so didn't think of using it :/ Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ no problem, glad you got it working. Feel free to accept an answer that has solved your issues

Answer (score 1):

For those who *can* use jQuery, you could do it in a `while` loop.

```
var $children = $(document.body).children();
while ($children.length) {
    console.log($children.attr('class'));
    $children = $children.children();
}
```

Or as @adeneo suggested, you can use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
$(document.body).find('*').contents();
```

Although, jQuery recommends to "[Avoid the All Selector,](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)" either way it's likely going to be expensive code.

Comment: sorry; can't use jQuery - but if I could, I would! So +1 anyway :)

Comment: I figured it was possible, but it's still a good solution to others who might see this question! :)

Comment: With jQuery it would simply be something like `$(doc.body).find('*').contents()`

Comment: @adeneo Nice suggestion, thanks! I will edit my answer.